# How to create a button that will check for update in google play in android?

Tags: android, button, auto-update

I want to create a normal button, clicking it; one can check whether there is a update version of this apps is available in google play or not.

While being connected to the internet, one can manually check for updates through out that button. Offline it will show a toast instead.

Is it possible?
If it is, please provide me some workable specific codes so that I can get a clear understanding what to do.

Comment: Question is too broad which you are asking to do so but You don't need anything to do these because it is already managed by Google Play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google play will display a notification if a new update is available or automatically update the app depending on the configuration.

Bottomline: a button in your app to check for updates does not make sense anyway